# Ruby struct reset method

Tags: ruby, object, struct

I have a large struct, and after creating an object and setting some of the members to values, I want to be able to set all the members of the object to nil. I tried the following, which doesn't work for some reason:

```
 My_struct = Struct.new(
   :member1,
   :member2,
   :member3
 ) do
   def reset
    self.each {|x| x = nil }
   end
 end

 myblock = My_struct.new
 puts myblock.member1
 myblock.member1 = "value"
 puts myblock.member1
 myblock.reset  
 puts myblock.member1
```

I expected that last puts to return "" but it returns "value". What have I done wrong? Is there a native method, other than destroying and recreating the object each time?

Comment: Your `each` block doesn't do anything. It assigns `nil` to the local variable `x`, but you don't do anything with that local variable, and it goes out of scope immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.each` is iterating over the values, not the members/keys of the struct. This should do what you want.

```
My_struct = Struct.new(
  :member1,
  :member2,
  :member3
) do
  def reset
    self.members.each {|k| send("#{k}=", nil)}
  end
end

myblock = My_struct.new
myblock.member1
#=> nil
myblock.member1 = "value"
#=> "value"
myblock.member1
#=> "value"

myblock.reset  
myblock.member1
#=> nil
```

Answer (score 2):

### Problem

> I have a large struct, and after creating an object and setting some of the members to values, I want to be able to set all the members of the object to nil.

### Solution: Just Replace the Whole Struct Object

Unless you have a special need to keep the object ID the same, the easiest thing to do is simply to create a new Struct, because the documentation for [Struct#new](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Struct.html#method-c-new) says:

> Unset parameters default to `nil`.

For example:

```
My_struct = Struct.new :member1, :member2, :member3
m = My_struct.new 'foo', 'bar', 'baz'    
#=> #<struct My_struct member1="foo", member2="bar", member3="baz">

m = My_struct.new
#=> #<struct My_struct member1=nil, member2=nil, member3=nil>
```

Obviously, `m.object_id` will differ every time you assign a new My_struct instance to *m*, but there are very few use cases where this would (or should) matter. It's certainly a lot easier and less prone to errors than trying to reassign individual members, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware that destroying and recreating a new instance on the old object name was as simple as repeating the .new method.

Comment: Very sensible solution. The preferred one, imo. (Aside: it may just be me, but the use of very large bold face grates.)

Answer (score 2):

```
My_struct = Struct.new(:member1, :member2, :member3) do

  def reset
    initialize
  end

end

myblock = My_struct.new
myblock.member1 = "value"
p myblock.object_id # => 15379000

myblock.reset
p myblock.member1   # => nil
p myblock.object_id # => 15379000; same object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
My_struct = Struct.new(
  :member1,
  :member2,
  :member3
) do
    def reset
      members.each { |m| self[m] = nil }
    end
  end

m = My_struct.new #=> #<struct My_struct member1=nil, member2=nil, member3=nil> 
m.member1 = "Billy-Bob"
m.member2 = "Girtie"
m.member3 = "Hector"

m.member1  #=> "Billy-Bob" 
m.member2  #=> "Girtie" 
m.member3  #=> "Hector" 

m.reset

m.member1 #=> nil 
m.member2 #=> nil 
m.member3 #=> nil
```

Answer (score -2):

I've tried with ruby 2.2.4. All fields a nil by default?
But I've found a way you could change fields you like

```
require 'pp'

MyStruct = Struct.new( :member, :user, :parent ) do
  def initialize
    self.members.each { | elem | self.send( "#{elem}=", 1 ) }
  end
end

pp MyStruct.new
```

UPDATE: I had to changed the code. Comment below was right. Now it's working

Comment: Your `each` block doesn't do anything. It assigns `nil` to the local variable `elem`, but you don't do anything with that local variable, and it goes out of scope immediately.